# Is it possible to use "already" with the past simple in this example?

Tags: past-vs-past-perfect

> I did not remember that I **already bought** it.
> or
> I did not remember that I **had already bought** it.

I think that past simple works as it is not a narrative and it is obvious that the action of buying comes first.

Comment: Either would be perfectly understandable by a native BrE speaker. Although most would probably say "I did not remember that **I'd already bought** it."

Comment: Being obvious is not always a reliable indicator of the appropriate tense. Much of the time, we automatically choose the most familiar pattern. Peter Jennings has identified it correctly, I think—except that if we're contracting "I had" to "I'd," we would probably also say "I didn't remember."

Comment: "Did not remember" is a bit strange to use here. It's more natural to say "I forgot [that] I'd already bought it" -  to forget = to fail to remember

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use "already". However, the difference between your two example sentences is not with "already" but with the verb tense: simple past vs. past perfect.

Because the action of buying occurred before the action of remembering, it should be in the past perfect:

> I did not remember that I had already bought it.

English speakers are often very loose with verb tenses, so many people might use the simple past instead:

> I did not remember that I already bought it.

This can occur even without "already":

> I did not remember that I bought it.

Even though the simple past is understandable in this case and is often used by native speakers, many people consider it to be an incorrect sequencing of verb tenses.